# Read Error message

Tags: 13.10

I am new to Ubuntu and did an install of 13.10 on a laptop. I get an error message

```
Error: Opening the cache (E:read error-read (5: input/output error), 
E:the package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.)'
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: error comes while running which command?

Comment: At the top of the screen I have a red circle with a with bar inside of it. When I click it I see the error message and it says to run package manager. When I run this I get the same error and it also says: E:the package lists or status file could not nbe parsed or opened.

Comment: Also says E:_cache->open() failed, please report.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot somewhere and include the link here. I need to see that 'red circle' you're talking about and the error message.